showing that $x^4+x^3+2$ is primitive over $\Bbb F_3$
I want to show that $x^4+x^3+2$ is primitive over $\mathbb{F}_3$. By definition, this means that $x^4+x^3+2$ is monic and has a root $\alpha$ that generates the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$, namely $\mathbb{Z}_{80}$. Thus, one of its four roots in $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ must have an order coprime to $80$ in $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$. This concept seems very abstract, and I'm struggling to grasp it properly.

It is possible to brute force this. I would not enjoy it, but I've seen (and done) worse. To get an idea of what that entails take a look at this old answer of mine where I show by brute force that a root $\gamma$ of $x^4+x+1$ in an extension field of $\Bbb{F}2$ is primitive (i.e. has order $2^4-1=15$). Undoubtedly you have already shown that $x^4+x^3+2$ is irreducible. This implies that $\alpha$ is an element of $\Bbb{F}{81}$ but not an element of a smaller field.

(cont'd) So we know that the order of $\alpha$ is a factor of $80$ (and is not a factor of $8$). As $80=2^4\cdot5$ your claim would follow, if you can show that neither $\alpha^{80/5}=\alpha^{16}$ nor $\alpha^{80/2}=\alpha^{40}$ is equal to $1$. That's not quite as taxing :-)

Hopefully you are aware of the good ole square-and-multiply.

Oh, and your next to last sentence is off. The task is to show that one of the roots has order exactly $80$ (rather than coprime to it). The (multiplicative) orders of all the (non-zero) elements of $\Bbb{F}_{81}$ are factors of $80$. By Lagrange's theorem from the first course on algebraic structures.

Name $f(X) \in \mathbb{F}_3$; $f(X) = X^4+X^3+2$. And $E=\mathbb{F}_3(f)$ the descomposition field of $f$
You can see that $G =Gal(E/\mathbb{F}_3)=C_4$. Consider the following polynomial:
$\hat{f}(X) = f(X+2) = X^4 + 2X +2$. Then if ${x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4}$ are the roots for $f$, then $\alpha_i = x_i + 1$; $i=1,2,3,4$ are the roots for $\hat{f}$, and the descomposition field is the same.
Now you can see that $\Delta^2=Discr(\hat{f}) = 2$, and $\sqrt{2}$ it’s not in $\mathbb{F}_3$. And the cubic solver is $g(X) = X^3+X+2 = (X+1)(X^2+2X+2)$ that has an unic root in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and its descomposition field is $\mathbb{F}_3(\Delta)$. Then you can see $G$ is $C_4$ and $f$ primitive.

Can you explain how the primitivity of $f$ is related to the fact that the splitting field of $g$ is $\mathbb F_3(\Delta)$?

Perhaps you missed the OP's definition of a primitive element/polynomial? Your answer is, unfortunately, irrelevant for the purposes of this question. See my old CW answer explaining the two notions both called primitive. Also, every finite extension of every finite field automatically is a Galois extension with a cyclic Galois group. Hail the Frobenius automorphism that generates it!

I accidentally upvoted this answer, but it's not what I'm looking for! I'm not even familiar with some of the notations used.
